# Set innerHtml of select element based on variable

Tags: jquery, django

How can I set the default value of an element by comparing the innerHTML to a variable?

This is the select box

```
<select name="added_by" class="form-item-added_by" required="" id="id_added_by">
  <option value="" selected="">---------</option>

  <option value="1">admin</option>

</select>
```

This is what I've tried, but nothing happens.

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        {%for note in notes%}
     added_by = "{{note.added_by}}"
     $(".form-item-added_by").val(added_by).change();
     {%endfor%}
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: I feel like this is trying to mix a server side loop with client side logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not going to work because you're changing the select based on the `value` which in this case is 1, so the variable `added_by` is not going to match anything.

Try this

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        {%for note in notes%}
     added_by = "{{note.added_by}}"
     $('.form-item-added_by').val(function(){
    return $('.form-item-added_by option').filter(function(){
                return $(this).text() === added_by;
           }).val();
});
     {%endfor%}
        });
    </script>
```